# Unable to run Meteor application on Webstom

Tags: meteor, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am able to run the Meteor application from the terminal.I am trying to run the meteor application from the webstorm and I am getting following error

I am using latest version of webstorm which is 9.0.1 and I have set up my application according the blog:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/meteor-support-in-webstorm-9/

Here is the error message :

> /Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
>                         throw(ex);
>                               ^ Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/cowboyxyz/rschtml5/ageroRSCHTML/.meteor/local/build'
>       at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:548:18)
>       at Object.files.renameDirAlmostAtomically (/Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/files.js:644:8)
>       at _.extend.complete (/Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/builder.js:485:11)
>       at writeSiteArchive (/Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1836:13)
>       at /Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2206:20
>       at /Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:250:13
>       at _.extend.withValue (/Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.
>       at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1926:31)
>       at bundleApp (/Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:509:28)
>       at _.extend._runOnce (/Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:527:24)
>       at _.extend._fiber (/Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:744:28)
>       at /Users/cowboyxyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.mewx50++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:380:1

Comment: such errors usually occur when current user doesn't have permissions for .meteor/local/build (see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/893, for example). Please check if it's owned by root and not by you.

Comment: I am able to run the application from the terminal; To run the application from the terminal I use 'sudo meteor' command ;Is there a way in webstorm to set up such a way to run the application as Sudo?

Comment: so my supposition is right - .meteor/local/build  is owned by root as a result of running with sudo. To run meteor as sudo from WebStorm, you have to run WebStorm itself as sudo. But to me this is a bad idea- you will likely have permissions problems later, when running as normal user.